# "Authorization": token does not pass CORS VUEJS APACHE

Tags: apache, vue.js, axios, cors

```
My FrontEnd Vue     


var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: baseUrl + '/v5/test',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": Token,
  },
};
```

My htaccess file

> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
> RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
> SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
>
> Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
>
> Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
> Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Authorization"
> Header always set Access-Control-Request-Headers: "Authorization"

i'm getting that error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'mydomain.com/v5/test' from origin 'app.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

My app is subdomain and API are in domain

Comment: i'm using the wildcard "*" properly, **BUT IF I REMOVE "Authorization": Token its pass cors**

Comment: same problem with my project, I'm still looking for an answer. I'm using vue quasar and php codeigniter for the back-end, only when I add authorization to header the CORS error occurs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi guys I fixed doing couple changes

first I add this one in my vue.config.js
if you want to build and deploy you just need to uncomment first one to server and second one to local environment

```json
    devServer: {
        //proxy: "https://subdomain.example.com/" 
        //proxy: "http://localhost/" // run in local
    },
```

Second
In your server I add the htaccess this one:

```xml
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(subdomain)\.example\.com$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    
    
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header unset Connection
    Header set Connection keep-alive
    
    Header unset Keep-Alive
    Header set Keep-Alive timeout=100,max=500
</IfModule>
```

Thats it the CORS was fixed

Answer (score -1):

This is the headers that I am using for CORS

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET
```

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve with that *.htaccess*

Comment: When sending in the header "Authorization": Token from axios, it gives me cors problems, but if I remove the "Authorization": Token from the axios header, the cors pass without problem, and the ** htaccess ** is set to that way for any request with "Authorization or without" Authotization to pass without cors problems but it doesn't work for me: /, does this @Babacar configuration go inside the axios headers?

Comment: nan this is going to your server configuration ie your expressjs app or laravel, ...